# How to enable just Second Screen Only?

Tags: display

For some reason i need to use only second screen. I have attached laptop with LCD monitor but now both screens are on while i just need one, I cant figure it out i have looked for it but didn't find a thing about it.
Help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to **System Settings** → **Hardware** → **Displays** (as in next image), select your laptop screen and turn it off:

[image: turn off laptop screen]

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, which will open the below 4 options. While holding down <kbd>Super</kbd>, select the 3rd option using arrow keys.

1. Mirror
2. Join Displays
3. External Display only
4. Built-in Display